# Calculate $f\left(x\right)=cxe^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}$ with $x>0$ (a) find c, (b)the mean of X, (c) the variance of X

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, variance, means

Calculate $f\left(x\right)=cxe^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}$ with
$x>0$ (a) find c, (b)the mean of X, (c) the variance of X

(a)$$E\left[X\right]=\int_{0}^{+\infty}x\cdot cxe^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx=c\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{2}\cdot e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx$$
Integrating by parts
$$\begin{array}{cc}
u=x^{2} & du=2xdx\\
dv=e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx & v=-e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}
\end{array}$$
$$E\left[X\right]=c\left(\left(x^{2}\right)\left(e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx\right)+2\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx\right)$$
Integrating by parts again
$$\begin{array}{cc}
u=x & du=dx\\
dv=e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx & v=-e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}
\end{array}$$
$$E\left[X\right]=c\left(\left(x^{2}\right)\left(e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx\right)+2\left[\left(x\right)\left(e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx\right)+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx\right]\right)$$

Still not sure if this is the right procedure.
(b) Missing
(c) Missing

Comment: That calculation is really for (b). In (a), use $c=1/\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2/2}dx$.

Comment: The problem statement in part (a) is unclear as stated. I believe the intention is to find $c$ so that $f(x)$ is a valid probability density function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(a)**

$f(x)$ is a valid pdf.

Therefore $$\int_0^\infty f(x) dx = c\int_0^\infty xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx = 1$$

Since  $$\int_0^\infty xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx = 1$$ therefore $c = 1$

**(b)**

$$E(X) = \int_0^\infty xf(x) dx = \int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

**(c)**
$$Var(X) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2$$

$$E(X^2) = \int_0^\infty x^2 f(x) dx = \int_0^\infty x^3 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx = 2$$

Hence
$$Var(X) = 2 - \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{4 - \pi}{2}$$